# Unable to redirect to new page using $location.path with Firebase login

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

**Issue:** On Firebase login, I would like to redirect the user to a new page.I am trying to use $location.path() in my controller even I tried using $state.go(). But it seems to be no use. Also I am not getting any error in console.

Using Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword method, Angularjs 1.5, ui-router and AngularFire.

login.service.js

```
var firebaseAuthObject = fbDbConn.auth();
function login(emailid, passwd) {
  return firebaseAuthObject.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailid, passwd);    
}
```

login.controller.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .controller('AuthController', AuthController);

  AuthController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', 'authService'];

  function AuthController($scope, $location, authService) {
    $scope.message = null;
    $scope.error = null;

    $scope.register = function() {
        return authService.register($scope.email, $scope.password)
        .then(function(userData) {
            $scope.message = "User created with uid: " + userData.uid;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;console.log(error);
        });
    };

    $scope.login = function() { 
        $scope.auth_error ="";
        return authService.login($scope.email, $scope.password)
        .then(function(authData) {
            $location.path('/app/overview');    //$state.go('/app/overview');
        }).catch(function(error) {console.log(error);
            $scope.error = error;
            $scope.auth_error = "Username or Password is wrong.";
        });
    };

    $scope.logout = function() {console.clear();
        authService.logout();
        $location.path('/login');
    };

  }

})();
```

config.route.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('singApp.login', ['ui.router','firebase'])
    .config(configFunction)
    .run(runFunction);

  configFunction.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

  function configFunction($stateProvider) {    
    $stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/modules/login/login.html'
      })
  }

  runFunction.$inject = ['$location', 'authService', 'firebaseDataService', 'PROTECTED_PATHS'];

  function runFunction($location, authService, firebaseDataService, PROTECTED_PATHS) {

    authService.firebaseAuthObject.onAuthStateChanged(function(authData) {
      if (!authData && pathIsProtected($location.path())) {
        authService.logout();
        $location.path('/login');
      };
    });

    function pathIsProtected(path) {
      return PROTECTED_PATHS.indexOf(path) !== -1;
    }
  }

})();
```

Thanks for help !!

Answer (score 0):

Just check the $state.go() method instead of $location

First inject the dependency '$state'

```
AuthController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'authService'];
```

Check your **routes.js** file.

The below is a sample code.

```
 app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/profile");
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'login.html'
        })
        .state('app.overview', {
            url: '/overview',
            templateUrl: 'views/overview.html'
        })
});
```

If everything correct then then you can use the below code for redirection.

> $state.go('login');

I'm using the '$stateChangeSuccess' event to find out the route changes.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$cookies', '$timeout',
    function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $cookies, $timeout) {
          $rootScope.$state = $state;
          $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;


          $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, nextRoute, toState) {
              console.log(nextRoute.name);
              // $state.go('login');
          });
     }
])
```

Comment: I have injected $state and also tried using $state.go('app.overview'); but both the methods are not working.

Comment: check uploaded config.route.js in main question. Hope so, it will help.

Comment: Check the function 'onAuthStateChanged' executing correctly or not

Comment: I was trying this method, but am not sure about this. In console.log(authData);  I get loggedin details about user like email, uid etc. Or should I use any other method?

Comment: Check my updated answer. If it's a router issue then I think this will help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126014/discussion-between-ti2005-and-kitti).

Answer (score 0):

first you should inject $state to your controller and   use $state.go('stateName')

$state.go('/app/overview') will  not work

you should use $state.go('stateName')

```
angular
    .controller('AuthController', AuthController);

  AuthController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location','$state', 'authService'];

  function AuthController($scope, $location, $state,authService) {
    $scope.message = null;
    $scope.error = null;

    $scope.register = function() {
        return authService.register($scope.email, $scope.password)
        .then(function(userData) {
            $scope.message = "User created with uid: " + userData.uid;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;console.log(error);
        });
    };

    $scope.login = function() { 
        $scope.auth_error ="";
        return authService.login($scope.email, $scope.password)
        .then(function(authData) {
           $state.go('stateName');
        }).catch(function(error) {console.log(error);
            $scope.error = error;
            $scope.auth_error = "Username or Password is wrong.";
        });
    };

    $scope.logout = function() {console.clear();
        authService.logout();
        $location.path('/login');
    };

  }

})();
```

Comment: I have injected $state and also tried using $state.go('app.overview'); but both the methods are not working

Comment: have you tried to set breakpoint in browser dev tools and see if it hit $state.go('stateName');? or do you have any error on console ?

Comment: after trying this I got console error something like this **Error: 'invocables' must be an object** even I googled about it but didn't got any proper anwser.

Comment: i suggest you put breakpoint in start of your methode and resumme by f10 to see where error happens